# Use AWS AppSync as a GraphQL Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, apollo-client, aws-appsync

I am trying to connect my react native mobile app with graphql server. For that, as the graphql client I am using [Apollo Client](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/). I hope to use AWS services and, I have a problem in selecting the suitable graphql server.

Can I use AWS AppSync instead of using a separate GraphQL server such as [ApolloServer](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/), [Express GraphQL](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/running-an-express-graphql-server/) etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use AWS AppSync as a GraphQL server on AWS. AWS AppSync is an AWS service for creating your fully managed GraphQL API layers. Since, it is a managed service, which means you don't need to worry about provisioning a server for your backend.

I would suggest you to use Serverless framework to manage and deploy your AppSync application. Here is the link for you to get started and will probably give you a good idea how to use Serverless for AppSync applications.

https://www.serverless.com/guides/aws-appsync

Comment: Hi, I have created an application using AppSync. I am using HTTP Endpoints method in it. It is not working in production but only working in development. Do I need to deploy it somewhere? Can I not directly create a build and access through graphQL endpoint given by Appsync?